# How to sort the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors in such way that each eigenvalue to its own corresponding eigenvector?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, mathematical-optimization, eigenvalues

I would like to find eigenvalues and the corresponding eigenvectors of the matrix AA.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

AA = {{1, 3, 2}, {1, 7, 2}, {1, 10, 2}}

Out[148]= {{1, 3, 2}, {1, 7, 2}, {1, 10, 2}}

Eigensystem[AA]

Out[149]= {{5 + 3 Sqrt[3], 5 - 3 Sqrt[3], 
  0}, {{-((-1 - 3 Sqrt[3])/(8 + 3 Sqrt[3])), -((-5 - 3 Sqrt[3])/(
    8 + 3 Sqrt[3])), 
   1}, {-((1 - 3 Sqrt[3])/(-8 + 3 Sqrt[3])), -((
    5 - 3 Sqrt[3])/(-8 + 3 Sqrt[3])), 1}, {-2, 0, 1}}}
```

Here `{5 + 3 Sqrt[3], 5 - 3 Sqrt[3], 0}` are the eigenvalues and `{-((-1 - 3 Sqrt[3])/(8 + 3 Sqrt[3])), -((-5 - 3 Sqrt[3])/( 8 + 3 Sqrt[3])), 1}, {-((1 - 3 Sqrt[3])/(-8 + 3 Sqrt[3])), -(( 5 - 3 Sqrt[3])/(-8 + 3 Sqrt[3])), 1}, {-2, 0, 1}` are the eigenvectors

How to sort the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors in such way that each eigenvalue to its own corresponding eigenvector?

Comment: They are already sorted that way, or am I missing something?  Sometimes people are confused by the fact that that for exact input (like your `AA`) the eigenvectors that come back are not normalized.

Comment: Transpose[Eigensystem[AA],{1}]  ?

Comment: @Jason B., do I understand correctly that the eigenvalue Eigensystem[AA][[1]][[1]] corresponds the eigenvector Eigensystem[AA][[2]][[1]] and for the other two: Eigensystem[AA][[1]][[2]] corresponds Eigensystem[AA][[2]][[2]] and Eigensystem[AA][[1]][[3]] corresponds Eigensystem[AA][[2]][[3]] ?

Comment: 4th point under Details and Options for [`Eigensystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html):
_All the nonzero eigenvectors given are independent. If the number of eigenvectors is equal to the number of nonzero eigenvalues, then corresponding eigenvalues and eigenvectors are given in corresponding positions in their respective lists. The eigenvalues correspond to rows in the eigenvector matrix._

Comment: Even for the trained mathematician the overloaded, detailed  description is not helpful. 

Its simply not understandable why the defining equation from any text on linear algebra

m   . Eigenvectors[m]^tr == DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[m ]]   .   Eigenvectors[m]^tr 

evaluates to False

Comment: @RolandF, `m . Transpose[Eigenvectors[m]] == Transpose[DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[m]] . Eigenvectors[m]]` returns `True`.

Comment: Yes, but as I  demonstrated,  (D. E)^tr = E^tr . D  for a diagonal D and thats not textbook convention for eigensystems.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that  the implementation of Mathematica satisfies the eigenvalue equation by index picking   M . EsM[[2, k]] == EsM[[1, k]] EsM[[2, k]]. This is of course of practical value.

Comment: @RolandF, Mathematica does not differentiate between row and column vectors, that is why sometimes you have to do some additional manipulation (like `Transpose`), and why some Mathematica code does not correspond one-to-one to mathematical equations. The documentation is quite clear in explaining how the values are put together, and which relationship holds (eg. `m.Transpose[vectors]==Transpose[vectors].DiagonalMatrix[values]`).

Comment: Everathing, clear exept for the documentation. One can find facts one knows about already. The indifference of Dot for 1d-vectors can of course be avoided if one notates column vectors as nx1 arrays always.  Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}}]    ->  {{1}, {2}, {3}}. To put everything into a list,  even a 1-row vector makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

They are sorted, but as a matrix of rows.

Lets see a complicated case

```
M = Array[RandomInteger[] &, {4, 4}]

{{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}

EsM= Eigensystem[M]

{{1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]), 1, 1, 1/2 (1 - Sqrt[5])}, 
{{-((-1 + Sqrt[5])/(-3 + Sqrt[5])), 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5]),
 -(4/(-3 + Sqrt[5])), 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0},{0, 0,  0, 0},
{-((1 + Sqrt[5])/(3 + Sqrt[5])), 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]), 4/( 3 + Sqrt[5]), 1}}}


(M . EsM[[2]]\[Transpose]) == (DiagonalMatrix[EsM[[1]]] . 
     EsM[[2]])\[Transpose] // FullSimplify

True
```

Since the transpose of a product is the the reverse product of the transpose, one has an eigenvalue equation from the right

```
(M . EsM[[2]]\[Transpose]) == EsM[[2]]\[Transpose] . DiagonalMatrix[EsM[[1]]]
```

True

The system is degenerate, two eigenvalues are equal, the system yields one of the two eigenvector as the null vector.

By design, the matrix of eigenvectors is not invertible directly. If the eigenvector matrix is invertible,  the equation  can be multiplied from the left by the inverse of the transpose in order to yield the diagonalized form.